# Is there a way to impl trait for a tuple that may have any number elements?

Tags: rust

I have a trait like this:

```rust
trait Foo {
    fn do_something(self) -> Self;
}
```

And I want implement this trait for a tuple that may have any number of elements that implement this trait.

```rust
impl<T> Foo for (T, T) where T: Foo {
    fn do_something(self) -> Self {
        let (t0, t1) = self;
        (t0.do_something(), t1.do_something())
    }
}

impl<T> Foo for (T, T, T) where T: Foo {
    fn do_something(self) -> Self {
        let (t0, t1, t2) = self;
        (t0.do_something(), t1.do_something(), t2.do_something())
    }
}

// and so on...
```

Comment: If all the items in the tuple are the same type, have you considered using an array or Vec instead?

Comment: Seems it's not possible for now. See how `Tuple` itself implements different traits: https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.5.0/std/primitive.tuple.html

Answer (score 8):

**Note:** I'm not sure whether you *should* do this, but here's a way to anyway. (Feels hacky to me, and that may be because I don't know how to make a better macro.)

## Homogeneous tuples `(T, T)`

The way you've described it:

`impl<T> Foo for (T, T) where T: Foo`

Here, the entire tuple *must* be homogeneous (i.e. `(MyType, MyType2).do_something()` will *not* work because of monomorphization).
**This raises a flag because tuples are for heterogeneous data.**

If implementing the trait only one homogeneous tuples is still what you want, we can implement a macro the way [the standard library does to implement traits for varied length tuples](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.35.0/std/primitive.tuple.html#implementations), with some modifications. (Click `src` on the right of an `impl` to see it's source.)

```
macro_rules! replace_expr {
    ($_t:tt $sub:ty) => {$sub};
}

macro_rules! tuple_impls {
    ( $( $name:ident )+ ) => {
        impl<T: Foo> Foo for ($(replace_expr!(($name) T),)+)
        {
            fn do_something(self) -> Self {
                let ($($name,)+) = self;
                ($($name.do_something(),)+)
            }
        }
    };
}

tuple_impls! { A }
tuple_impls! { A B }
tuple_impls! { A B C }
tuple_impls! { A B C D }
tuple_impls! { A B C D E }
tuple_impls! { A B C D E F }
tuple_impls! { A B C D E F G }
tuple_impls! { A B C D E F G H }
tuple_impls! { A B C D E F G H I }
tuple_impls! { A B C D E F G H I J }
tuple_impls! { A B C D E F G H I J K }
tuple_impls! { A B C D E F G H I J K L }
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=9ccf55a0f3b85452ae35b872da84dac9)

### Heterogeneous tuples `(T1, T2)`

If you're okay with `(MyType, MyType2).do_something()` working (where both implement the `Foo` trait), you can try this simpler macro:

```
macro_rules! tuple_impls {
    ( $( $name:ident )+ ) => {
        impl<$($name: Foo),+> Foo for ($($name,)+)
        {
            fn do_something(self) -> Self {
                let ($($name,)+) = self;
                ($($name.do_something(),)+)
            }
        }
    };
}

tuple_impls! { A }
tuple_impls! { A B }
tuple_impls! { A B C }
tuple_impls! { A B C D }
tuple_impls! { A B C D E }
tuple_impls! { A B C D E F }
tuple_impls! { A B C D E F G }
tuple_impls! { A B C D E F G H }
tuple_impls! { A B C D E F G H I }
tuple_impls! { A B C D E F G H I J }
tuple_impls! { A B C D E F G H I J K }
tuple_impls! { A B C D E F G H I J K L }
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=c50e3a702034b4360d9f3ad9dd2d86d2)

Comment: No, use arrays.

Answer (score 2):

No. (unless you are ready to use macros - see other answers)

Tuples in Rust have a fixed length [just like arrays](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/ch03-02-data-types.html#compound-types). I do not believe you can express the concept of "tuples of any length".

In other words a tuple of 2 elements is a different compound type than a tuple of 3 elements. If you insist on using tuples you have to go for the solution you outlined above.

Use a collection? (such as aliasing an existing one and implementing the trait on it)?